# Maven plugin development: goal dependency

Tags: java, maven-plugin

It's vary hard to find proper search query for my question so I hope it's not a duplicate.

I'm developing maven plugin with few goals. I'd like to combine two of them in the chain (lifecycle?). Before `clean-checkout` goal is executed I would like to execute `checkout` goal first. I'm using annotation approach and tried using `@Execute` annotation to point which goal should be executed. The plugin compiles but is not executed in the way I assumed, cause there is no preceeding `checkout` goal while executing `clean-checkout`.

```
@Mojo(name = "checkout", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.GENERATE_SOURCES)
public class Checkout extends AbstractMojo {

@Mojo(name = "clean-checkout", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.GENERATE_SOURCES)
@Execute(goal = "checkout", phase = LifecyclePhase.GENERATE_SOURCES)
public class CleanCheckout extends AbstractMojo {
```

Without `defaultPhase` and `phase` properties, the build was failing.

Where I'm doing mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a custom lifecycle might help you.
Two years ago I analyzed the maven-release-plugin in more details and noticed that they use their own lifecycle.

Here you can find their lifecycle definition:
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/release/tags/maven-release-2.3.2/maven-release-manager/src/main/components-fragment.xml?view=markup

Additionally I found details inside Sonatype's Mavenbook:
http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugins-lifecycle.html

This interesting blog might also help you:
http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/08/create-a-customized-build-process-in-maven/